# fread() with reading binary file containing hex in C

Tags: c

I am trying to read a binary file containing hex. As you can see from the picture of the binary file. However, the output will not produce 01. I have already opened file and I used fseek() to point to beginning of the file. Below I have three lines in my program that should print out 01.

[image: Binary File]

```
unsigned char begintag[2];
fread(&begintag,1,1,ptr_myfile);
printf("%x",begintag);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "binary file containing hex"? Do you have a text file with hex-encoded values? Or a "true" binary file containing arbitrary bytes that you then want to *show* as hex?

Comment: `printf("%x %x", (unsigned int) begintag[0], (unsigned int)begintag[1]);` (but you only read one character)

Comment: It should be `printf("%x", (uinsiged int) begintag[0]);`, otherwise you are printing the address of `begintag`.

Comment: I think it's a little weird that you say "a binary file containing hex".  If it's a binary file, it just contains bits.  You may want to visualize or consume that binary data as hex characters, but I don't think it makes sense to say that a binary file contains hex.  Hex is a way to look at data.  Now, a text file might contain hex because hex is a textual representation of data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is a true binary file containing arbitrary bytes that we want to show as hex

Comment: please see the picture labeled Binary File

Comment: What the other users are trying to say, is that your phrasing is misleading at best, it's wrong. A 'hex' is just a representation of a scalar value, just as 13 is the representation of the scalar 13, because we humans cannot picture a scalar in our heads without useful representations. Hence saying "a binary file containing hex" is nonsense. Every file contains sequences of 1s and 0s, grouped together can be interpreted as a value in binary form. From that you can change the representation to decimal, hex, octal, etc.

Comment: Usually we use hex representation for binary files, because it's much easier to read `0A` instead of `1010`.

Comment: @wildplasser this would print one good hex value, the other is undefined as the OP only reads 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `begintag` as an array, so you should not put an ampersand `&` front of it in the `fread` call. Now you are assigning the value read from file to the memory address value the variable is pointing to. The following code prints hex value of the first byte in `"in.bin"` file calling `fseek` and `fread`. Although you could use simply `fgetc` to read the byte: (Warning: No error checking here)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  FILE *f;
  unsigned char c[2];

  f = fopen("in.bin", "r");
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
  fread(c, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, f);
  printf("%02x\n", c[0]);

  fclose(f);

  return 0;
}
```